# OpenXML extract Highlighted text from word document with c#

Tags: vb.net, openxml

I used the following, but it won't work

```
Dim htext= wordDocument.MainDocumentPart
                       .Document
                       .Descendants(Of Highlight)()
                       .Where(Function(h) h.Val = "yellow")
                       .ToList()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this method to get list of highlighted text.

```
Private Function GetListOfHighlightedString(ByVal Docx As WordprocessingDocument) As List(Of String)
                Dim lstOfHighlightedString As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)()
                Try
                    For Each EachRun In Docx.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Descendants(Of Run)()
                        If EachRun.RunProperties IsNot Nothing Then
                            For Each EachPrpChild In EachRun.RunProperties.ChildElements
                                If TypeOf EachPrpChild Is Highlight Then
                                    Dim highlightVal As Highlight = TryCast(EachPrpChild, Highlight)
                                    If highlightVal.Val.Equals(HighlightColorValues.Yellow) Then
                                        lstOfHighlightedString.Add(EachRun.InnerText)
                                    End If
                                End If
                            Next EachPrpChild
                        End If
                    Next EachRun
                Catch e1 As Exception

                    Throw
                End Try
                Return lstOfHighlightedString
```

Comment: Having to rebuild my solution.  I screwed of my packages.  I will respond by Monday at the latest.  thanks for your help.

Comment: Doesnt seem to pick up on the highlighted items.  The check for Eachrun IsNot nothing is always empty.  I pass a WordProcessingdocument is that not correct?

Comment: RunProperties is Nothing

Comment: OK, got it to at least get the highlighted text.  I fixed the highlighting in my document. Once that was solved I changed the If condition to highlightVal.Val.Value.Equals(HighlightColorvalues.Yellow)  Now I got all my highlighted values.  Just gotta figure out how to make it by each paragraph?

Comment: Can't add Example of my code I used to get it to work how I needed.